Impedance matching between two differential ports
I am attempting to match a 50 ohm differential source impedance with a 150 ohm differential load over a wide band (1-15 Mhz) for a receive path.
I am trying to figure out if I can use only a single transformer to match the signals but I'm not sure if it's possible. It's for an IQ receiver so I would prefer to use as few components as possible to keep the IQ signals as matched as possible.
Are there any other options besides converting the differential signal to single ended and then converting that to differential again at the proper impedance?
Thanks


I am trying to figure out if I can use only a single transformer to
match the signals but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Of course it's possible and you need to focus on why you think it isn't.
For instance a 1:3 impedance transformation is achieved with a step-up transformer ratio of \$1:\sqrt3\$ so, what's not difficult about this?

Are there any other options besides converting the differential signal
to single ended and then converting that to differential again at the
proper impedance?

I don't think so; a properly designed transformer will work. I mean 1 to 15 MHz is bread and butter for the correctly designed transformer.
